# Catch errors coming from node module folder

Tags: node.js

I have node js project which uses mongoose and in mongoose I get the error "Unknown modifier $pushAll" which I saw whats all about it is just about versions in mongoose. I don't have any control over this file in node_modules and we have made it to work despite this error.

My problem is that it always gives UnhandledPromiseException to the console and log files which is annnoying.

My question is - How can I prevent a file,function, module or whatever exicsting in node_modules to write anything in the console? How can I catch the error given in a promise in a file I have no control over?

Comment: Can you share the code where you're using `$pushAll`?

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574 for a possible solution to your error. It looks like that modifier may have been recently deprecated.

Comment: @djfdev Sadly I can't show the code as its not mine. It is automatically called when I try to push something to an array and then send it to the database. The code giving the error is not mine and it is located in node_modules folder. What I want is to remove the error from the console. I have made a workaround so that it saves the object in the database but I still get the error even though the code works. The error is annoying though.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase: at some point in your code, you are calling a function from the mongoose library. At this point, an error occurs. Can you share that part of your code which calls mongoose? It seems likely that there is something in your code which is causing the error to occur, but without seeing code it’s hard to tell.

Comment: This is also partially based on what I read in the link I shared, which I believe is describing the same issue you’re dealing with.

Comment: I.e. try adding usePushEach: true to your model schema options